# systemd: how can I run a script on start of a service, without editing the service definition

Tags: systemd

Scenario:

Before and after a MariaDB starts, we would like to run a script to generate and dstroy some configuration files. Ideally we would do this without touching the core mariadb.service file installed by the package manager.

i.e.

```
service mysql start
```

Should automatically run another script/service *before* starting and another script/service *after* starting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `systemd edit servicename.service` you can apply local overrirdes to things in the unit.  For your request you might want to adjust these values.

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=beforestuff
ExecStopPost=afterstuff
```

If you override using the edit command the changes will probably get saved to `/etc/systemd/system/servicename.service.d/override.conf`.

Links:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

Comment: This was what I needed, thank you. In fact, I wanted to be able to do this programatically, so I simply create a ".conf" file at /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.d/mycustomization.conf.

Works a treat.